# Model training: difference between inference, marginalisation, and estimation

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, inference

I am working through the lecture slides of Carl Rasmussen's Probablistic Machine Learning course. In slide 6 of the [first lecture](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/teaching/4f13/1617/modelling%20data.pdf) it lists a number of ways that one can learn the parameters (A, C) and latent variables (x) of a model, e.g.:

[image]

They are:

1. *inference*
2. *estimation*
3. *sampling*
4. *marginalisation*

I am struggling to find exact definitions of all of these. Inference I think means evaluating the posterior probability distributions of all the variables. While sampling I think means approximate inference with MCMC. Is this correct?

Would estimation be methods like MAP and MLE? What does marginalisation mean here? I thought marginalisation is a part of inference.